# How to save space when the object is in Hidden mode?

Tags: javascript, xml, odoo, qweb

I want to save space when I put a hidden object in Css and javascript, my goal is to hide the head on page> 1 when I generate a pdf (Sale order for example), I want the logo to remain in the other pages, so I use the addon '' Report Qweb Element Page Visibility '' goal space is not win, it remains a big gap

Comment: Where is your script?

Comment: Sorry the script is a bit long, the site does not give me permission, so it's in the addon Report Qweb Element Page Visibility

Comment: You don't have to post the whole thing, just a [mcve].

Comment: I think you can't remove the whole header area, that's why the logo is hidden but the area is just white and remains. Try to set negative margins on the first div of your document to shift this div into the header area on the first page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using hidden, which is a value of visibility, you should use display: none;
To make it reappear, just set it to display: block.

Comment: Thank you, I did what you told me, plus I adjusted between margin-top, padding-top and header spacing, my problem it's resolve.